# PHP won't trim on jQuery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, trim

So I'm having really strange problem...

After

```
         $.ajax({
                url: WEB + 'tools/tags/',
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    search: search
                },
```

I catch search with my PHP script. I'm trying to trim it, and without any success. Eg. if I enter "  test", and after trimming that in my PHP script, i still get " test".

```
    $search = $this->request()->post('search');
    $trimmed = trim($search);
    die(print_r('Res' . $trimmed));
```

Anyone have a clue what could be the problem!? 
I tried putting search on the end of ajax request URL (with get method), then tried to send it via POST method, ran my PHP script with debugger... I'm running out of ideas ><
:)

BTW: The search variable in my JS script : var search = _tagsInput.text(); It's text() because it's a contenteditable div.

UPDATE 1: So I tested my "BTW" that I mentioned above, it looks like the .text() is causing the problem, and my content editable div. After I sent something in normal textbox, it worked. Anyone had similiar problem with content editable div content ?

Comment: Have you tried jquery `$.trim()`?

Comment: My guess is the text is being sent with `&nbsp;` entities rather than normal whitespace.

Comment: could you use `var_dump($trimmed);` instead of `die(print_r())` ?

Comment: I'm aware of jquery trim method, but really wanna see how it can be done on server side . Btw, i var_dump-ed input '___123' and i got string 'Â  Â 123' (length=8)  (replace ___ with blank spaces)

Comment: okay another one, I tried utf8_encode($this->request()->post('search')); and got "Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  AAAasd"...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be ok in your code. I did not find the problem. If you want to remove blank spaces from the searhc var. Then you can also use the jQuery trim method for it like following. Thanks

```
$.ajax({
                url: WEB + 'tools/tags/',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    search: $.trim(search)
                },
```